# Getting a child's parent in JDO

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I'm running into the issue of the child not having the reference to its parent. Supposedly I've got the setup of a bidirectional relationship where I can get children from the parent and get the parent from the child; however my childrens' parents are always coming back null.

I've got a parent of,

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Company {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent(mappedBy = "company")
    private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
}
```

With a child of,

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Employee {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent
    private Company company;

    @Persistent
    private String username;
}
```

I'm persisting the object by,

```
Company newCompany = new Company();
Employee newEmployee = new Employee();
newEmployee.setUsername("ryan");
newCompany.getEmployees().add(newEmployee);
pm.makePersistent(newCompany);
```

I'm accessing the object like so,

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(Employee.class,"username == s");
query.declareParameters("String s");
List<Employee> employees = (List<Employee>)query.execute(username);
pm.close();

if (employees.size() > 0)
{
    Employee employee = employeeList.get(0);
    ...
}
```

I'm then seeing "company" as null when debugging while the rest of the employee's fields are populated. Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

Comment: care to share how you are retrieving objects, and where you are checking something is null ... and please put in any transaction begin/commit boundaries, and/or object lifecycle states

Comment: Additional details have been provided.

Comment: and the object is in what state ? persistent-clean ? detached ? and if detached, did you request that the company field be detached? JDOHelper.getObjectState(obj).

Comment: The state appears to be "transient". No detach request was made.

Comment: so the field will be null, i.e they are no longer managed (pm has been closed etc). Suggest you pay more attention to where you get the objects from and where you close the PM

Comment: You were indeed right about the pm being closed, however removing the close now has the object in the state of "hollow/persistent-nontransactional" and the parent is still null.

Comment: I now noticed that the parent will appear null until it is fetched from the child at which it is populated and returned as expected. Thank you very much for your help. Please do submit an answer to my question with your answer stating I've closed my pm so that you may get proper credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetching of the parent depends on where you check it, according to the object state. If your PM has been closed by that point then it will not have fetched the parent field. Touching the parent field before closing the PM (and having retainValues set to true, or detaching at close of the PM) will result in the parent field being set.